# callee allocates callee frees

Tags: c++, c, security, memory-management

In the book "Secure Coding in C and C++", the author mentions three different ways to manage strings across a project.

1. Caller allocates, caller frees (C99, OpenBSD, C11 Annex K)
2. Callee allocates, caller frees (ISO/IEC TR 24731-2)
3. Callee allocates, callee frees (C++ `std::basic_string`)

Then he mentions, "*The third memory management mode, in which the callee both allocates and frees storage, is the most secure of the three solutions but is available only in C++.*"

Why is the third mode most secure?

Comment: How do "caller" and "callee" relate to "across a project"?

Comment: This sounds like a gross simplification, and not good advice.

Comment: Also, C and C++ are very different languages and idioms that make sense for one will not make sense for the other. You should probably pick a language you're interested in for the purpose of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the statement that the third method is only available in C++ is nonsense.
All three methods are possible in both C and C++.

Regarding the "*secure*" part, it depends on what you're doing. If you're writing a self-contained string class (like eg. `std::basic_string`), the third method is likely the best because the class self-manages it's own memory completely.

A string class relying on memory allocations/deletions in main (or any other external part) is an invitation to forget the necessary allocations when using strings. (=high probability of bugs)